# Error with index global in Lua recipe for foldit.org

Tags: lua, global

I am just starting writing scripts for [Foldit](https://fold.it/portal/). This is my first experience of Lua, so my status is "noob with insight". In my first script, I want to print out `contactmap` data. I have copied and pasted the functions from http://foldit.wikia.com/wiki/Foldit_Lua_Functions. The error I get is:

`attempt to index global 'structure' (a nil value)`

Here is my code:

```
segmentCount = structure.GetCount()
print ("Segment count: " .. segmentCount)

for source = 1, segmentCount do
  for target = source + 1, segmentCount do
    inContact = contactmap.IsContact(source, target)
    heat = contactmap.GetHeat(source, target)
    print("Segments "..source..", ".. target..": heat = "..heat)
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment.

---

EDIT

The problem was that I had originally loaded a V1 recipe, and foldit continued to treat it as V1 syntax. The solution was to create a New (ScriptV2) recipe, and load exactly the same code.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing everything according to the documentation. The error means that `contactmap` is not defined (has `nil` value) and the code fails on accessing its elements. I'd check the version of Foldit you are using as the documentation says that `contactmap` is new in version 2.

Comment: I have discovered the problem. I had originally loaded someone else's recipe that had been written using V1. Apparently, even after I had loaded in my own script (written in an external text editor), foldit was still considering that the recipe should be treated as V1. When I created a new (V2) recipe and loaded my script, it ran fine.